# What is the Offset class?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Can someone please explain the Offset class in flutter:

1. What is it and its purpose?
2. What is the meaning of dx and dy? (does it mean delta x and delta y?

The documentation gives no examples and their explanation is vague.

Here is the documentation if you are wondering: [Offset Class Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Offset-class.html)
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Simply it is a data class to store X and Y coordinates and pass that class data to other classes or functions. In other programming languages this class is called **Point**, and in dart, it is called **Offset**. Also, the **Offset** class gives you some helper methods and operators to work with.

Answer (score 2):

One example for the use of Offset is when you add a boxshadow to a container, you can use the Offset to change the "position" of the BoxShadow decoration.

```
boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
      blurRadius: 3.0,
      offset: Offset(5,3),
      color: MyColors.grey.withOpacity(.5),
)],
```